# Boxes with space between (different width/height)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation, gutter

I'm trying to build an element for a magazine website, where the first element consists of post promotion boxes with different widths and heights like on the following pic:

[image: promo boxes]

- I'm using ZURB Foundation
- I need a gutter between the boxes like on the pic
- Using collapse and appropriate image sizes, I can get the desired result, but without gutters between the pics.
- When I define custom foundation gutters manually, the height of the left pic changes for some pixels

Here is my approach:

```html
<div class="row collapse">

  <div class="column medium-6"><!-- Left Pic 50% width --></div>

  <div class="column medium-6">
  
    <div class="row collapse">

      <div class="column medium-12"><!-- Right Top Pic 50% width, 50% height --></div>

      <div class="column medium-6"><!-- Right Bottom Left Pic 25% width, 50% height --></div>
      
      <div class="column medium-6"><!-- Right Bottom Right Pic 25% width, 50% height --></div>
    
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a good scenario for [Grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

The basic idea is to create a template of the desired grid using `grid-template` property on the parent container and later to assign each area to the children elements with `grid-area` property.

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwBqBE?editors=1100)

---

**Markup**

```
<section class="grid">
  <div class="item first">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/600/500" />
  </div>
  <div class="item second">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="item third">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/149/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="item fourth">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/149/100" />
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
   width: 600px;
   height: 250px;
   display: grid;
   grid-column-gap: 3px;
   grid-row-gap: 3px;
   grid-template:
     "first first second second" 1fr  
     "first first second second" 1fr
     "first first second second" 1fr
     "first first third fourth" 1fr
     "first first third fourth" 1fr / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid .first  { grid-area: first;  }
.grid .second { grid-area: second; }
.grid .third  { grid-area: third;  }
.grid .fourth { grid-area: fourth; }
```

Images can be added either as regular `img` elements or as backgrounds, as you prefer.

---

**Result**

[image]